# Metrics of datasets?

Tags: dataset

It is quite common to discuss what metrics to be used for a model/algorithm/method. But when it comes to metrics of datasets, it is much less discussed.

I wonder, what are the general metrics for datasets? That is to say, how does one quantitively measure if a dataset is good or not for its purpose?

I understand, there may not be too many general metrics, given the purpose and nature of datasets differ vastly. So, more specifically, I am interested in the follow few cases:

what are the metrics for 1) text datasets, 2) classification datasets, 3) unbalanced classification datasets?

Any knowledge, insights, interesting ideas are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: The question is too vague in my opinion. Metric for what? Metrics are rarely computed in isolation but are computed to serve some particular objective. So, you have metrics that evaluate model fit because the goal here is to assess how well different models fit a particular data set. Similarly, you have metrics for evaluating speed of an algorithm because the goal is to design faster algorithms etc

Answer (score 1):

For unbalanced datasets, please refer to http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~hrangwal/kd-hcm/proc/papers/3-Perez-Baranauskas.pdf

Comment: Could you summarize in few words the main ideas from Perez and Baranauskas's paper, and tell us why you think that might answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Datasets are usually considered as input upon which we wish to perform some task (e.g. classification, clustering, ...). A 'purpose', is therefore not generally considered for a dataset, but instead on the model which is applied to the dataset.